# Undefined variable ao tentar adicionar um valor na sessão

Tags: php

O arquivo template.php:

Código HTML:

```
<html>
...

<table border="3">
        
            <tr>
                <th>Tarefas</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Prazo</th>
                <th>Prioridade</th>
                <th>Concluída</th>
            </tr>
            
            <?php foreach($lista_tarefas as $tarefa){ ?>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$tarefa['nome'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$tarefa['descricao'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$tarefa['prazo'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$tarefa['prioridade'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$tarefa['concluida'];?></td>
                </tr>
                
            <?php } ?>
        
        </table>

...
</html >
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php 
    
        session_start();
        
        if(isset($_GET['nome']) && $_GET['nome'] != ''){
            $tarefa = array();
            $tarefa["nome"] = $_GET["nome"];
        
        if(isset($_GET['descricao'])){
            $tarefa['descricao'] = $_GET["descricao"];
        }else{
            
            $tarefa['descricao'] = '';
        }
        
        if(isset($_GET["prazo"])){
            
            $tarefa['prazo'] = $_GET['prazo'];
            
        }else{
            
            $tarefa['prazo'] = '';
        }
        
        $tarefa['prioridade'] = $_GET['prioridade'];
        
        if(isset($_GET['concluida'])){
            $tarefa['concluida'] = $_GET["concluida"];
        }else{
            
            $tarefa['concluida'] = '';
        }
        
        $_SESSION['lista_tarefas'] = array($tarefa);
            
        
        }
        
        include "template.php";
```

E na parte da `view`

Erros dado:

> Notice: Undefined variable: lista_tarefas in
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Alguém sabe como exibir e não mostrar esses erros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando acessar uma variável indefinida.

```
<?php foreach($lista_tarefas as $tarefa){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$tarefa['nome'];?></td>
        <td><?=$tarefa['descricao'];?></td>
        <td><?=$tarefa['prazo'];?></td>
        <td><?=$tarefa['prioridade'];?></td>
        <td><?=$tarefa['concluida'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Neste trecho você utiliza `$lista_tarefas` como se ela estivesse definida igual a `$_SESSION["lista_tarefas"]`, mas essa conversão da sessão para uma variável não é feita sozinha. Você precisa definir o valor da variável:

```
$lista_tarefas = $_SESSION["lista_tarefas"];
```

Comment: @NitrousHang por favor, exclua os comentários acima para não poluir o site.